# Qt :How to make hyperlink to exe file

Tags: qt

Hello simple question but i can’t find the answer .
i present in label full path to exe file on the desktop , how can i make it clickble hyperlink
that will launch the exe ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code :

```
QLabel *lbl = new QLabel;
lbl->setText("<a href='file:///c:/fg740p.exe'>Open</a>");
lbl->setOpenExternalLinks(true);
lbl->show();
```

substitute **c:/fg740p.exe** with the path to your .exe file. 
And as you may know **Open** is what displayed to user.

Comment: strange thing when i combain it with text its format me the link as plain text but if i do as you showen its working for example for not working :
ui->labelDone->setText("blah blah  your desktop.\n"
 "<a href='file:///"+path+"'>Open</a>" );
and working :
ui->labelDone->setText("<a href='file:///"+path+"'>Open</a>" );
how can i combain the 2?

Comment: @user63898 ~> Use complete HTML : `lbl->setText("<html><head/><body>Blab blab blab<br/>"
                 "<a href=\"file:///c:/fg740p.exe\">Open</a></body></html>");`

Comment: @user63898 If your path is a variable, then construct a QString first. `QString url("<a href='file:///"); url += path; url += "'>Open</a>"; lbl->setText(url);`

Answer (score 3):

saeed's code should work on Windows, but on other platforms security is stricter and the operating system might not allow you to lauch an external application in this manner (Linux, for example.)

The portable way to do this is to first create the QLabel as usual:

```
QLabel* label = new QLabel(parent);
```

Then put a link in it:

```
label->setText("<a href='dummy_string'>Execute</a>");
```

and then connect the linkActivated(QString) signal to a slot so that you get notified whenever a link inside the label was clicked:

```
connect(label, SIGNAL(linkActivated(QString)), SLOT(onLinkClick()));
```

Since there's only one link inside the label, the slot doesn't need to take an argument, as there's no need to distiguish between links.  So it can be something like:

```
void onLinkClick()
{
    QProcess::startDetached("path/to/program.exe");
}
```

If you instead choose to use a slot that takes a QString, the passed value will be the `href` text of the link. This allows you to put several links in the QLabel and know which of them was actually clicked. For example:

```
label->setText("<a href='path/to/1.exe'>Run 1.exe</a>"
                <a href='path/to/2.exe'>Run 2.exe</a>");
connect(label, SIGNAL(linkActivated(QString)), SLOT(onLinkClick(QString)));
// ...

void onLinkClick(QString exeFilePath)
{
    QProcess::startDetached(exeFilePath);
}
```